# How to SELECT json data from postsgreSQL WHERE key="1"?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I have stored JSON data in column "data".
I want to retrieve ONLY those rows where the key is "1".
The problem is that None values are also being fetched and when I use a WHERE clause to remove None values, I run into an error.

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT data -> '1' FROM table WHERE data != %s''',(None,)) 
data_list= cursor.fetchall()
```

The error I get-

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: json <> unknown 
LINE 1: SELECT data-> '1'  FROM table WHERE  data!= NULL
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The data column looks like this-

```
[(None,), (None,), (None,), ({'1':{"post":{salary: 100000 , "shift": "first" }}} ,), ({'1':{"post":{salary: 180000 , "shift": "second" }}},), (None,), ({'2':{"post":{salary: 20000 , "shift": "first" }}})]
```

I am using the python psycopg2 module.

Comment: Kindly provide a representation of the `data` table. The scenario may be easier to understand if show what your db table looks like

Comment: Added data column

Comment: Would you want to extract your rows to python first, then filter the data you need? Instead of trying to filter directly with MySQL

Comment: I want to filter directly from SQL because the number of rows are expected to be 50k+ which would presumably slow down the program if I try parsing after extraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?` operator to check if a key exists in the top level of a `jsonb` value.

```
SELECT data->'1'
       FROM "table"
       WHERE data ? '1';
```

Comment: Data type is json.

Comment: @pundit: In the long run you should then redesign the schema and use `jsonb` instead. Meanwhile you can upcast to `jsonb` (`... data::jsonb ...`). (and that's why you should have provided a proper [example] including the table's DDL in the first place, so I would have known it's just `json`.)